# Report not running inside JasperReports Server

Tags: php, jasper-reports, jasperserver

I am trying to run a report, which I designed in *iReport*, on my *JasperReports Server*. But when I try to run the report I am getting the following error.

> Error Message
>
> Error filling report Error Trace
>
> com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.JSException: Error filling report at
>   com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl$FillResultListener.reportFillError(EngineServiceImpl.java:1233)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.BaseFillHandle.notifyError(BaseFillHandle.java:211)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.BaseFillHandle$ReportFiller.run(BaseFillHandle.java:135)
>   at
>   com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl$SynchronousExecutor.execute(EngineServiceImpl.java:880)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.BaseFillHandle.startFill(BaseFillHandle.java:165)
>   at
>   com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl$AsynchronousReportFiller.fillReport(EngineServiceImpl.java:836)
>   at
>   com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl.fillReport(EngineServiceImpl.java:1702)
>   at
>   com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl$ReportFill.runWithDataSource(EngineServiceImpl.java:1057)
>   at
>   com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl$ReportFill.runReport(EngineServiceImpl.java:991)
>   at
>   com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl$ReportRunnable.run(EngineServiceImpl.java:902)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) Caused by:
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error preparing statement for
>   executing the report query : select * from
>   sp_report_projectwise('?','?','?') at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRJdbcQueryExecuter.createStatement(JRJdbcQueryExecuter.java:372)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRJdbcQueryExecuter.createDatasource(JRJdbcQueryExecuter.java:196)
>   at
>   com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.util.JRTimezoneJdbcQueryExecuter.createDatasource(JRTimezoneJdbcQueryExecuter.java:168)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.createQueryDatasource(JRFillDataset.java:1112)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.initDatasource(JRFillDataset.java:689)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.setParameters(JRBaseFiller.java:1281)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:900)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.BaseFillHandle$ReportFiller.run(BaseFillHandle.java:120)
>   ... 10 more Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column
>   index is out of range: 1, number of columns: 0. at
>   org.postgresql.core.v3.SimpleParameterList.bind(SimpleParameterList.java:51)
>   at
>   org.postgresql.core.v3.SimpleParameterList.setLiteralParameter(SimpleParameterList.java:112)
>   at
>   org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.bindLiteral(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:2174) at
>   org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.setInt(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:1212)
>   at
>   org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.setInt(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:116)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRJdbcQueryExecuter.setStatementParameter(JRJdbcQueryExecuter.java:520)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRJdbcQueryExecuter.setStatementParameter(JRJdbcQueryExecuter.java:399)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRJdbcQueryExecuter$1.visit(JRJdbcQueryExecuter.java:332)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRAbstractQueryExecuter$QueryParameter.accept(JRAbstractQueryExecuter.java:157)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRAbstractQueryExecuter.visitQueryParameters(JRAbstractQueryExecuter.java:646)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRJdbcQueryExecuter.createStatement(JRJdbcQueryExecuter.java:317)
>   ... 17 more

Comment: Could hel us and describe a bit more your environment? From what I see you use a postgresql db. The main issue seems to be linked with the data you get vs the data you expect: 

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column index is out of range: 1, number of columns: 0

My guess is your query does not return what you expect...

Comment: @TocToc        Yes. I am using postgresql with yii framework and the report have three parameters.I am trying to run the report in jasper server and show it in my php application using the php client for jasper server. I have designed the report using iReport and have successfully run it using phpjasperxml class. But the problem with phpjasperxml class was that functions and expressions cannot be used in the report. So now I am trying to run the report within jasper server and show it in my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the parameter was placed inside single quotes. For phpjasperxml class the parameter should be enclosed within single quotes, where as for running in jasper server single quotes should not be there.I removed the quotes and it worked.